# Roximity beacons Android SDK

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon-android

I'm trying to create an app to work with ROximity beacons. I've tried to use Roximity 1.2 SDK, but had no success launching the app with it and because time is short - I was forced to use a demo project with 0.2 SDK, which was workin +/- ok.
Problem is - I cannot find any method in SDK to stop scanning for beacons and update interface, so when I close the app - scanning thread is still scanning (it is started somewhere in SDK automagically) and instead of proper closing it crashes.
Unfortunately, Roximity support isn't supporting much and they cannot provide any documentation, because there's not to much of it anyway and what is there - it is very very minimal: http://roximity.github.io/ROXDOX/roxandroid_s_d_k.html

Answer (score 0):

The Roximity SDK is a modified version of an older version of the open source [Android Beacon Library.](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) You can review the documentation for the open source library at the link provided to see if helps with any questions.  Obviously, Roximity's modifications may change the way things work. Worst case, you can simply switch to using the open source library.

With the open source library, you can stop scanning two ways:

1. Unbind all BeaconConsumer instances from the BeaconManager. (Preferred)

   ```
   beaconManager.unbind(this);
   ```
2. Set the background between scan period to be very large and put the BeaconManager into background mode.

   ```
   beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(Long.MAX_VALUE);
   beaconManager.setBackgroundMode(true);
   ```

Full disclosure: I am the author of the open source library.

Comment: I am also using Roximity Latest SDK and need to find exact distance from the beacons in feet. I have posted a question here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32253823/how-can-i-get-exact-distance-in-feets-from-the-beacon-using-roximity-sdk
will be grateful if you can help thanks.