# How can i get exact distance in feets from the beacon, using roximity sdk?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, proximity, ibeacon-android

I am using Roximity SDK and it gives beacons range update but only with three points Far, Near and Immediate, while i want to get their distance in feets, any idea how can i get this ?
Here's the code i have used according to roximity SDK docs.

```
private void createBroadcastRecievers(){
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(ROXConsts.MESSAGE_FIRED);
    intentFilter.addAction(ROXConsts.BEACON_RANGE_UPDATE);
    intentFilter.addAction(ROXConsts.WEBHOOK_POSTED);

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
}

private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals(ROXConsts.MESSAGE_FIRED)) {
            MessageParcel messageParcel = (MessageParcel)intent.getParcelableExtra(ROXConsts.EXTRA_MESSAGE_PARCEL);
            handleMessageFired(messageParcel);
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(ROXConsts.BEACON_RANGE_UPDATE)){
            String rangeJson = intent.getStringExtra(ROXConsts.EXTRA_RANGE_DATA);
            handleBeaconRangeUpdate(rangeJson);
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(ROXConsts.WEBHOOK_POSTED)){
            String webhookJson = intent.getStringExtra(ROXConsts.EXTRA_BROADCAST_JSON);
            handleWebhookPosted(webhookJson);
        }
    }
};
```

and in my handleBeaconRangeUpdate method i am getting following attributes only as

"beacon_id" = unique identifier of the beacon.
"beacon_name" = beacon name as set in your ROXIMITY Dashboard
"beacon_tags" = tags associated with this beacon, as set in your ROXIMTIY Dashboard
"proximity_value" = the proximity value integer of the beacon when triggered. 1 = Immediate 2 = Near 3 = Far
"proximity_string" = the string representation of your beacon proximity when triggered. "Immediate" "Near" or "Far"

this only provides limited values of distance as Near, Far, Immediate while i need exact in feet's. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: @Lourens i have added the code, please let me know if you have worked on roximity sdk thanks.